# AngularJS ng-style not changing with property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I cant seem to figure out why the style property is not getting updated. In my larger application it seems to work fine.

```
angular.module('Model', [])
    .factory('SizeModel', function () {
        return {
            width: 200,
            height: 100,
            display:"block",
            getCombined: function() {
                return parseInt(this.width) + parseInt(this.height);
            }
        };
    });

function AlbumCtrl($scope,SizeModel) {
    $scope.master = SizeModel;
    $scope.$watch("master",function(){
    $scope.myprop = { display: $scope.master.display,
                      backgroundColor: "#333",
                      width: $scope.master.width+'px',
                      height: $scope.master.height+'px',
                      color: "#FFF"
                     };
        });

}

function AnoCtrl($scope,SizeModel) {
    $scope.master = SizeModel;

    $scope.toggle = function(){
        $scope.master.display = "none";
    }
}

function EditCtrl($scope,SizeModel) {
    $scope.master = SizeModel;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ganarajpr/C2hRa/4/

Here is a fiddle which shows the issue I am currently facing. You will notice that the width and height are getting updated in the div when you change the input. But the style itself doesnt seem to be updating. Anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong here?

I have tried all the following scenarios

1. using $scope.$apply.. - Throws an error stating $apply already in progress..
2. $rootScope.$apply - same as above.
3. Setting another variable in a service which is $watched in the other controller. - no change seen.

It would be really cool if someone can get me an answer to this. Also would be really happy if you can tell me why exactly it is not getting updated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You had assigned the width and height values to the myprop style field on a one-off basis.  So when you changed the width or height the myprop was not changing.

Change the myprop value to a function that computes its value instead...

http://jsfiddle.net/DyHHJ/

Comment: Again .. this solves the issue that I isolated into this context. What I would really like to know is how the two cases differ...

Comment: I got my answer.. In fact it even solved some older issues of mine :) Thanks a lot... for the answer :)

Comment: THANKS A TON!!! I have been hunting for a solution to how to return multiple properties to ng-style and your jsfiddle example completely nailed it! I can't thank you enough!

Comment: In your fiddle you're adding a watch on master and recreating the myprop function each time it changes.  This should be unnecessary, simply creating the function once seems to work as each time it's run it will get the latest values anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$scope.$watch` in the AlbumCtrl only watches [reference inequality](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch), which is determined by strict comparison via the !== Javascript operator.  Because you are changing only a property on the object, the reference to `master` is still the same and doesn't fire the $watch. You need to pass an additional argument to $watch to use objectEquality.  See this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/wFSqeSiceXtPrO904kJM?p=preview), and here is the relevant code below:

```
$scope.$watch("master",function() {
  $scope.myprop = {
    display: $scope.master.display,
    backgroundColor: "#333",
    width: $scope.master.width+'px',
    height: $scope.master.height+'px',
    color: "#FFF"
  };
}, true);
```

The third argument `true` tells angular to determine inequality of the watchExpression by the angular.equals function. It correctly determines that the the updated `master` object has been changed, and updates `myprop`