# NG Style Failing to automatically bind to page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to make a page with two sections, which can be slid back and forth horizontally to take up different relative widths on the page. The idea was to track the percentile width of the (to-be) draggable bar separating the two panes/sections, and use `ng_style` to automatically update the widths of the two "panes" in relation to where that bar is dragged.

The following is in a Rails app, with integrated Angular. The Angular's loading just fine -- no errors, and the rest is all working -- and the `ng_style` is being loaded from the Angular controller when the page first loads up -- but it's not changing when I attempt to drag the spacer in between the two "panes", as it's supposed to.

Here's a simplified version of my HAML (sorta like Jade. Just indented HTML):

```
  #full-page.fluid{ ng_controller: "ExerciseCtrl", ng_mousemove: 'updateSidebarWidth($event)', ng_mouseup: 'untrackMouseMove()', ng_cloak: true }
    .spacer
    .fixed-section-container
      .exercise-show
        %div
          .sidebar-section{ ng_style: '{{ sidebarWidthStyle }}' }
            .sidebar_header  

            .sidebar
              %div{ markdown: @exercise.body }
          .sidebar-toggle{ ng_mousedown: 'trackMouseMove()' }
          .work_area{ ng_style: '{{ workAreaWidthStyle }}' }
```

And here are the relevant lines in my (Coffeescript) Angular Controller.

```
  $scope.sidebarWidth = 35
  $scope.trackingMouse = false

  $scope.trackMouseMove = -> $scope.trackingMouse = true
  $scope.untrackMouseMove = -> $scope.trackingMouse = false

  $scope.updateSidebarWidth = (event) -> 
    if $scope.trackingMouse
      pageWidth = $('.emelyn-layout.middle.fluid').width()
      x_percent = (event.pageX * 100) / pageWidth
      x_percent = Math.max( Math.min(100, x_percent), 0 )
      $scope.sidebarWidth = x_percent
      $scope.workAreaWidthStyle = { width: "#{99 - $scope.sidebarWidth}%", marginLeft: "#{$scope.sidebarWidth + 1}%" }
      $scope.sideBarWidthStyle = { width: "#{$scope.sidebarWidth}%" }
```

In other words, I have this `.sidebar-section` on the left, then a `.sidebar-toggle` (just a vertical bar), which should be draggable (which causes the width styles to change, once I get this working), and then the `.work-area`, which is resized, along with the `.sidebar`, on drag of the toggle.

The issue is that, although the `ng_styles` are loaded on page load, and although the `ng_style` values visibly change when I inspect the page and drag the toggle bar, the `ng_style` changes aren't propagating to the `style` attributes of the given elements.

In other words, when I inspect the element, I see something like this:

```
<div class="work_area" ng_style="{ 'width':'48.142857142857146', 'marginLeft':'51.857142857142854' }">
```

I took a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736957/angular-ng-style-not-changing-with-property) and tried wrapping updates to the styles in a `$scope.$watch`, but that didn't change any of the above behavior at all, and it seems wrong to me -- the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) on `ng_style` suggest to me that the way I'm using it *should* be effectively correct -- as in, Angular handles the binding for you, without your needing to explicitly tell it when to update the DOM jQuery style.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it? (Or what might be a better or easier way of doing the above?)

Thanks, and please let me know if you'd like to see any other files or anything,

Sasha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ngStyle works a little differently than what you have. It is evaluated as is, no need for `{{}}` to point to a `$scope`d variable.

```
#full-page.fluid{ ng_controller: "ExerciseCtrl", ng_mousemove: 'updateSidebarWidth($event)', ng_mouseup: 'untrackMouseMove()', ng_cloak: true }
    .spacer
    .fixed-section-container
      .exercise-show
        %div
          .sidebar-section{ ng_style: 'sidebarWidthStyle' }
            .sidebar_header  

            .sidebar
              %div{ markdown: @exercise.body }
          .sidebar-toggle{ ng_mousedown: 'trackMouseMove()' }
          .work_area{ ng_style: 'workAreaWidthStyle' }
```

When you use `{{}}` it evaluates that to a string and then runs it through ngStyle. ngStyle ends up watching a string and not a variable.

Comment: Ha. The solution is always like a two-character change. Thanks so much for pointing that out.